# How to read result from Console.WriteLine() in Output window in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, console.writeline

To simply it, I just add one line in the Web Application:

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
```

What I want is to read "Hello, world!" on the output window in Visual Studio 2010, but failed, what's wrong?

[image]

I've tried:
change verbosity by Tools > Options > Project and Solutions > Build and Run and change values of "MSBuild project build output verbosity"
but without any effect.

Comment: The build verbosity controls how much information the compiler outputs. You can see this by changind the value of the "Show output from:" combo box from "Debug" to "Build".

Comment: Web applications do not deal with the console window.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) instead of `Console.WriteLine` if you want to see the result in the Debug window.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: Using the `WriteLine` method, I'm not seeing anything printed to the Debug window. I expect a List<string> to print out, but nothing's printed out. I have debugged at run-time and verified the list holds 32 items

Comment: @Kevin - Are you using `Debug.WriteLine`? How are you converting your `List<string>` to _a_ string?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Debug.WriteLine("Hello world")` (located in the System.Diagnostics namespace) to output to the debug window.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [TextWriterTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx). Have look at MSDN post - [Walkthrough: Integrating ASP.NET Tracing with System.Diagnostics Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd.aspx).